# Advice on UnitOfWork with NHibernate and/or Web Service

Tags: c#, nhibernate, unit-of-work

I'm looking for some advice for the following.

I need to create a DAL that is interchangeable between a database and a webservice. 
I'm developing in C# and WPF.

has anyone see any good implementations of an IUnitOfWork and allows different DAL to be switch in or out using some sort of DI?

**EDIT**

So after doing some reading. I've decided to use a Repository Pattern. The Rep Pattern takes in a IUnitOfWork. Above reads the opposite way around. Also here is an example for what i mean with the switch in or out.

```
NHibernateProductRepository : IRepository<Product>  
{
    private IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork = null;

    public NHibernateProductRepository(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
    {
        _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;    
    }
}

WebServiceProductRepository : IRepository<Product>  
{
    private IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork = null;

    public WebServiceProductRepository (IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
    {
        _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;    
    }
}

....

public static class Bootstrapper 
{
     public static void Load() 
     {
         // Some sort of IOC.. Which will also be used for DI. 
     }
}
```

So I guess I need help with the IUnitOfWork stuff. The Web Service Repositories are going to be tricky. So how do I create some sort of transaction, and how do I queue etc etc.

One last thing, in a WPF environment multiple threads could be saving things to the database, so for each thread should it create it's own UnitOfWork? I'm scared a thread could commit half way through another etc.

Comment: What do you mean with switching DAL in or out?

Comment: Hi Paco, i've updated my question to explain, cheers i'm a lame question asker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check out  [SharpArchitecture](http://www.sharparchitecture.net/) if you go with NHibernate. The contrib project has your scenario covered.

Comment: I've looked through the Northwind example. Do you know if anyone has used UnitOfWork with this also?

Comment: I found the UnitOfWork stuff this looks awesome. Cheers